# How to clear browser cache between routes AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, caching, browser-cache

I have tried several things to clear browser cache while routing between pages.like `cache: false` , `index.html?x=1` ,`target="_self"` ,`disableCache: true, in $routeProvider as well`.but any of this didn't worked for me.finaly `$window.location.reload();` worked.but i do not want reload the page every time when routing.is there any perfect solution for route cache in AngulerJs?

**scenario**

In my `header.html` have `ng-if="currentPath ==='/store'"`.it's check current path and display some styles regarding to `store` in `header.html`

**header.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-if="currentPath ==='/store'">
    <div class="col-xs-8 buttons" >
      <a class="brand" href="#" target="_self"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
      <a class="btns" href="#Store" target="_self">Store</a>
    </div>

<ul class="col-xs-4 icons">
      <li ><a href="#/profile" class="display_name"><i class="fa"></i>{{user.email}}</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/cart"> <span ng-show="cart_size > 0" class="count">{{cart_size}}</span></a></li>
 </ul>
<--some styles for store.......-->
</div>
<div class="container" ng-if="currentPath !=='/store'">
    <div class="col-xs-8 buttons" >
      <a class="brand" href="#" target="_self"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
      <a class="btns" href="#Store" target="_self">Store</a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

**current issue**

when i go into `store` page i have to refresh browser to display store styles in header.
after that go into another page,store styles still display in header.then i have to refresh again.
how to solve this issue?

Comment: you can set versioning to your js files. it will help you to load the template properly.

Comment: you can try `$templateCache.removeAll()` to remove template cache

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
angular.element('html[manifest=saveappoffline.appcache]').attr('content', '');
```

where you want to disable cache.

The manifest attribute specifies the location of the document's cache manifest.

As per [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_manifest.asp)

> HTML5 introduces application cache, which means that a web application
>   is cached, and accessible without an internet connection.
>
> Application cache gives an application three advantages:
>
> 1. Offline browsing - users can use the application when they're offline
>      Speed - cached resources load faster
> 2. Reduced server load - the browser will only download updated/changed resources from the server
>
> The manifest attribute should be included on every page of your web
>   application that you want cached.
>
> The manifest file is a simple text file that lists the resources the
>   browser should cache for offline access.
>
> To learn more about how to create the manifest file, please read our
>   HTML5 Application Cache chapter.

Another solution that you can try is add following snippet on your angular apps header so that your page will never be cached.

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Comment: I've tried meta tags.but don't know where do i want to put `angular.element('html[manifest=saveappoffline.appcache]').attr('content', '');`?

Comment: may i know where you put location.reload

Comment: in my `Controller` i've defined a function and `location.reload ` is inside that function.then i called that function to `<a ng-click="reloadfun()" href="#store">`.

Comment: you can put it in that  location insted of location.reload